# Вне всякого сомнения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вне всяких сомнений — вне всякого сомнения?
Нужно ли в тексте заменять "вне всяких сомнений" на "вне всякого сомнения"?

Answer (score 1):

Не только не нужно, но и неправильно. Форма множественного числа на мой взляд гораздо более естественна для подобных случаев отрицания с помощью "без". Сравните: без комментариев, без происшествий.

Comment: Нацкорпус дает 11 страниц примеров с ед. ч. и 5 страниц — со мн. ч. Все же склоняюсь к тому, что здесь устойчивое сочетание и в качестве вводной конструкции используется именно в ед. ч.

Comment: А по каким запросам? Впрочем, не суть важно.
Во всяком случае императивности единственного нет, так что *править* - как минимум не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

И один, и другой вариаенты вполне приемлемы, однако чаще в речи мы слышим вариант с единственным числом: "вне всякого сомнения". На это указывает и то, что если мы из данной фразы выбросим слово "всякий(всякие)", то обнаружим, что выражение "вне сомнения" обычно употребляется в речи. Кроме того, существительные, обозначающие отвлеченные понятия (сомнение, влечение, мечтание, мышление, понимание и т.п.), обычно употребляются в единственном числе, хотя множественное число у них возможно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не могу "наградить", поскольку нет очков-баллов ))

Comment: Я вам добавил.

Comment: Никак не могу согласиться, что "сомнения" относится к группе сементического singularia tantum (категории слов с множественным числом, не используемым по соображениям семантики). Мышление и понимание - да, это именно те отвлеченные существительные, множественное число для которых не образуется или несвободно. А мечтания, сомнения, впечатления, хоть и относятся к отвлеченным, во множественном едва ли не более употребительны чем в единственном. Это совсем другой разряд слов, "отвечающих" за эмоциональное состояние.